# Capture Adaptive Card response in Ms Teams Graph beta API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, chat, adaptive-cards

I try to send out an adaptive card on the Ms Teams chat using the  [beta API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).
Everything works as expected.

However, I need assistance to capture the response of user from an Action.Submit button.

Regards,
Aarushi

Answer (score 0):

You may find the doc articles linked below helpful. In addition to the docs listed below, I would suggest they use the App Studio app from inside Teams to test their cards – it is the quickest way to see how they will render there. Because every channel controls how they implement support for Adaptive Cards, the only real way to test is to view the card in that particular channel.

[Add card actions in a bot - Teams | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#adaptive-cards-actions)